# Как получить количество подписчиков и видео канала Youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Нужно получить количество подписчиков и видео у канала на Youtube

Comment: А что вы уже попробовали? Покажите пример кода. Смотрели ли вы в  документацию? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

Answer (score 3):

[С англоязычого SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161377/fetch-youtube-subscribers-count-by-json-api-in-php):

```
$youtube_url = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/googlechrome?v=2&alt=json' ), true );
$youtube_data = $youtube_url['entry']['yt$statistics']['subscriberCount'];
```